# Using matlab to change the color of the polygons of a map from a shp file

Tags: matlab

My question is that how do I change the polygons of a map from shp file (shapefile) while using matlab. I was doing this project where i was given map in shpfile format that I need to use on, I am able to read the map in matlab but the map is divide in regions and each regions have its color, my problem I met was to change the polygons to its respective colors, anyone sees this please kindly help and reply me asap.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Mapping Toolbox by The MathWorks, or third-party codes such as ones from the Shapefile C Library to import the shapefile?  If you are using the Mapping Toolbox, I cannot be of much help here as I do not have that toolbox -- hopefully, someone else can help here.

In any case, if you could import the shapefile on to your MATLAB Workspace, you should be able to find the vector data (polygons and attributes data, etc.) somewhere...

If you do not see anything on the Workspace, possibly you can find those data in the Figure (or in the Axis).

> data=get(the_handle);

I would look for the data there.

After you obtain the polygon and properties data, you can patch/fill them with any color you like (based on any other information you find there.)

Good Luck